# No puedo conectarme a bases de datos de SQL server. Error 18461

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me voy al **Configuration Manager** del SQL Server, en **Servicios**, y selecciono mi instancia. Me dirijo a la pestaña **Startup Parameters** y añado:

> -m
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reinicio el servicio, vuelvo a SQL Server y al tratar de loguearme sucede lo siguiente:

> ---
>
> Cannot connect to DESKTOP-RNDJSP2.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-RNDJSP2\mateo'. Reason: Server is in
> single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18461)

¿Alguien tiene idea de como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Uhmm... Ya investigaste el error en los foros de Microsoft? Cuando buscaste el error en google, qué palabras utilizaste? Ya intentaste entrar como admin? Parece que tu usuario no es parte del grupo de administradores de SQL Server.

Comment: En Google busqúe el número del error, busqué videos en youtube, pero sin suerte. 
Por lo que entiendo es como decis, no se me reconoce como administrador... Pero no sé cómo o dónde cambiar esa configuración. 
Mismo, ya probé viendo las propiedades de la dabatase que me aparece disponible y la configuración predeterminada es "MULT_USER"

Answer (score 0):

Recientemente me ocurrió el mismo error.

Pero que no es un error en si. Lo que pasa es que  estas configurando el servidor para que se inicie en modo de un unico administrador y una sola conexión, asi que cuando intentas logearte nuevamente, te dara el error **18461** que es el que te sale.

Lo que debes hacer es volver a configurarlo a multiconexiones o multiusuarios (no se si son los terminos correctos) pero es para que te puedas conectar más de una vez. Y debes configuarar la opción **`-f`** en vez de `-m`.

Espero te funcione. Saludos